# Trouble opening ionic modal from google maps custom control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have a google map with a custom control and I want it to open an ionic modal when clicked. I have another control that clears markers from the map and it is working fine.

If I put `modal.show` as the function for the button, I get "Cannot read property '$$destroyed' of undefined" when I click it.

If I put `modal.show()` the modal opens when the page loads, which I do not want, and then won't open again when I click the button.

## Controller

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function(mapServ, mapFact, $ionicModal, $scope){
  var vm = this;

  var gmap = mapServ.init();
  var markers = mapServ;

  // Create modal and Custom Map Controls
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    vm.modal = modal;

    var controlContainer = document.createElement('div');
    var clearControl = new mapFact.Control(controlContainer, 'Clear Map', mapFact.clearMap);
    var locControl = new mapFact.Control(controlContainer, 'Locations', vm.modal.show());

    controlContainer.index = 1;
    gmap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlContainer);
  });

   // Create Markers
   mapFact.markers($rootScope.rests, gmap).then(function(results) {
   mapServ.markers = results;
   vm.markers = mapServ.markers;
 });
});
```

## From the Factory

```
// Button Constructor
map.Control = function(controlDiv, text, func) {
  // Set CSS for the control border.
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#ed5929';
  controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #ed5929';
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
  controlUI.style.marginRight = '22px';
  controlUI.style.marginTop = '22px';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = 'Click to toggle markers';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  // Set CSS for the control interior.
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.color = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
  controlText.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '16px';
  controlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
  controlText.innerHTML = text;
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);
  controlUI.addEventListener('click', func);
};
```

Comment: Please clarify, what output do you want to exactly achieve? First, you said "I want it to open an ionic modal when clicked" but you also said "If I put modal.show() the modal opens when the page loads, which I do not want". And, can you also please share error logs when using `modal.show()`? :)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want the button to open the modal but I do not want it to open automatically when the page loads. There are no errors when I use `modal.show()` just the modal opens on page load and then nothing happens when pushing the button.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of implementing modal in Ionic as given in the [Ionic - Javascript Modal](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ionic/ionic_js_modal.htm).

You can either add separate template or you add it on top of the regular HTML file, inside script tags. First, you need to connect your modal to controller then create modal. After that, create functions for opening that will be triggered. Lastly, create a button to trigger `modal.show()` to open modal.

Sample HTML Code:

```
<button class = "button" ng-click = "openModal()"></button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have been able to open an ionic modal without issue though. The issue is with attaching the `modal.show()` method to the google map button. My other google map button works fine but the one to open the modal does not work as expected.